# ModelSerializer POST should be flat, while GET should have depth of 2

Tags: python, django, model, django-rest-framework

So, I have this model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True) # Allow anonymous articles
   url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   date = models.DateTimeField()
   status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And this serializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.modelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('user', 'date', 'status')
        depth = 2
```

With this viewset:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all(=
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

So I get everything related to the user in one request.
Problem is, if I want to add an Article I have to add a whole bunch of nested json now. I'd rather just reference the user by id and be done with it.

Like:

```
{
    "user": 1, // Or even null
    "url": "http://test.tld",
    "date": now,
    "status": "published"
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? I assume I need another serializer just for writing the data? How to I bind all of this together?

If I want to POST JSON like this I get an error saying "Non-Field-Errors" because "customer" has a few more relations attached and because of "depth" they would need to be filled as well. But I want to just provide a customer-id and be done with it.

Comment: Do you have [nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) that you aren't showing?

Comment: @RossRogers: No, I use HyperlinkedModelSerializers throughout the rest of the application but the problem is that if I want to POST an article I get "Non-Field-Errors" because well I would have to specify the whole customer with all it's sub-relations and that's just too deep ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use property in DRF and it should do what you are looking to do

```
class Article(models.Model):
   _user = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True, db_column="user_id") # Allow anonymous articles
   url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   date = models.DateTimeField()
   status = models.CharField(max_length=255)

@property
def user(self):
    return self._user
@user.setter
def user(self,value):
    self._user = User.objects.get(id=value)
```

And then on the serializer

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.modelSerializer):
    user = serializers.Field(source='user')

class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ('user', 'date', 'status')
    depth = 2
```

that will return the user object when you are readin the JSON, you can modify the @property to get what you require

Comment: Basically this would be an interesting solution, the problem is that user now says: "user" = "User object" instead of actual data whenever I GET the article. Is there any way around this?